# npm install package through running node container

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, npm-install

I've followed the steps in the node.js [documentation](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/nodejs-docker-webapp/) for creating a Dockerfile. I'm trying to run the command `docker exec -it mynodeapp /bin/bash` in order to go inside the container and install a new package via npm, but I get the following error

```
OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:346: starting container process caused "exec: \"/bin/bash\": stat /bin/bash: no such file or directory": unknown
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

for ref this is how my docker-compose and dockerfile look like

```
FROM node:latest

RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app

RUN npm install -g nodemon

COPY package.json package.json
RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 8080
CMD [ "node", "server.js" ]
```

and

```
version: '3'

services:
  nodejs:
    container_name: mynodeapp
    build: .
    command: nodemon --inspect server.js
    ports:
      - '5000:8080'
    volumes:
      - '.:/app'
    networks:
      - appnet
networks:
  appnet:
    driver: 'bridge'
```

Comment: `docker exec mynodeapp -it /bin/sh` ?

Comment: Same no luck. I've also tried `docker-comose exec nodejs /bin/bash` but didn't work

Comment: Using `docker exec` to install packages in a container, in itself, doesn't seem like a good idea: that change will get lost as soon as the container exits.  Add the dependency to your `package.json` file, test it locally, and re-run `docker-compose build`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `docker exec mynodeapp -it /bin/bash` to `docker exec -it mynodeapp /bin/sh`

According to [docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/) the correct syntax is the following:

> docker exec [OPTIONS] CONTAINER COMMAND [ARG...]

- `-i` and `-t` are the options
- mynodeapp is CONTAINER
- /bin/bash - is
  a COMMAND inside container

And another problem is that there is no `bash` shell inside container, so you can use `sh` shell.

Comment: I did this but didn't work either. `docker exec -it mynodeapp /bin/bash` was what I did on first place actually and the tried the other way around too

Comment: What is the error when you try `docker exec -it mynodeapp /bin/bash` ? Is it the same as when you try `docker exec mynodeapp -it /bin/bash`? You can also try `docker exec -it mynodeapp /bin/sh`

Comment: `OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:346: starting container process caused "exec: \"/bin/bash\": stat /bin/bash: no such file or directory": unknown`

Comment: Try `docker exec -it mynodeapp /bin/sh`

Comment: It works, thank you! why this `/bin/sh`is this different? Can you update your answer so I can approve it if you want?

Comment: Updated. `/bin/bash` and `/bin/sh` are different realisations of shell. In some OS  `/bin/bash` is not installed.